# Need to fix my footer to the bottom

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to put a footer at the bottom of the page.

I am unable to make [this page's](https://vitas.sk/sluzby.php) footer correct.

I tried a lot tips and trick that I found but nothing helped me.

I do not want the position fixed, I want the footer under the content.

Comment: How about adding position:fixed; and bottom:0; to your footer element?

Comment: if you use position fixed with bottom:0 or margin-bottom:0 you can still produce the effect you want. Look at @ChrisHappy's answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this too your `footer` style:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 10;
```

Entire style sheet:

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Half Slider (http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/half-slider)
 * Copyright 2013-2017 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-half-slider/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; 
}


footer{display: block;color: white;width: 100%;background-color: rgb(28,28,28);text-align: center;padding: 10px;position: fixed;bottom: 0;z-index: 10;}
.cock {
 
}
.telicko {
 
 height: 95.5%;

}
.sicko {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 5%;

}

.snavik{
 float: left;
    margin-top:8vh;
   
}

.nav {
 list-style-type: none;
 text-decoration:none;
}


.jednicka a.active{
 background-color: rgb(50,134,171);
 color: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.dvojka a.active{
 background-color: rgb(202,76,77);
 color: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.trojka a.active{
 background-color: rgb(219,162,10);
 color: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.stvorka a.active{
 background-color: rgb(132,177,58);
 color: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
.patka a.active{
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.jednicka a {
 color: black;
}

.dvojka a {
 color: black;
}

.trojka a {
 color: black;
}

.stvorka a {
 color: black;
}

.patka a {
 color: black;
}

.jednicka:hover a {
 background-color: rgb(50,134,171);
 color: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.dvojka:hover a{
 background-color: rgb(202,76,77);
 color: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
}


.trojka:hover a{
 background-color: rgb(219,162,10);
 color: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
}


.stvorka:hover a{
 background-color: rgb(132,177,58);
 color: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
}


.patka:hover a{
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.objb{
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 margin-top: 2%;
}


.sobrazky {
 margin-top: 4%;
 margin-bottom: 7vh;
}
.objbb {
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
}
.odpovede {
 margin-top:8vh;
 margin-left: 20vw;
 
 
 height: 100%;
 width: 70%;
 

}

.ulicko {
 margin-left: -26px;
}
.carousel-item {
    height: 50vh;
    min-height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#PART1{
 padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    width: 80%;
    height: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;


    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    

   


}
#PART2a{
 padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    
 position: absolute;
   top: 45%;
   left: 25%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

   


}

#PART2b{
 padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    
 position: absolute;
   top: 70%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

   


}

.smenu{
 position: absolute;
 top: 15%;
 left: 3%;
 
}

.snav {
 list-style-type: none;
}


   .nav-item a:hoover{
    color: rgb(236,212,146);
   }

.uo {

 width: 40%;
 display: block;
 
 margin-top: 40%;
}
.medzera {
 height: 5vh;
 width: 100%;
 
}
.tretiavec {
 width: 35%;
 padding-left: 5%;
}
.krok1{
 
 display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
 font-size: 150%;
 color: black;
 border:2px solid rgb(216,192,126);
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: rgb(236,212,146);
 

}
.krok2{
 
 
 display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
 font-size: 150%;
 color: black;
 border:2px solid rgb(216,192,126);
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: rgb(236,212,146);
 


}
.krok3{
 
 display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
 font-size: 150%;
 color: black;
 border:2px solid rgb(216,192,126);
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: rgb(236,212,146);



}

.txta {
 width: 20vw;
 height: 15vh;
}

.formularo {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
 left:10%;
 margin-top: 2%;
 padding-bottom: 7%;
 width: 80vw;
 display: flex;
}
.idd{
 text-align: center;
}
.contactformularo{
 border-right: 2px solid black; 
 width: 33%;
 padding-right: 5%;
}
.objto {

 
   margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 10vh;

}
.lolo {
 text-align: center;
}
.containerch {
 display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    
    width:100%;
}

.chbox1, .chbox2, .chbox3, .chbox4, .chbox5 {
 position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;

}

#checkmark1{
 border: 1px solid rgb(50,134,171);
}
#checkmark2{
 border: 1px solid rgb(202,76,77);
}
#checkmark3{
 border: 1px solid rgb(219,162,10);
}
#checkmark4{
 border: 1px solid rgb(132,177,58);
}
#checkmark5{
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.containerch:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.containerch input:checked ~ #checkmark1 {
    background-color: rgb(50,134,171);
}
.containerch input:checked ~ #checkmark2 {
    background-color: rgb(202,76,77);
}
.containerch input:checked ~ #checkmark3 {
    background-color: rgb(219,162,10);
}
.containerch input:checked ~ #checkmark4 {
    background-color: rgb(132,177,58);
}
.containerch input:checked ~ #checkmark5 {
    background-color: black;
}
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.containerch input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
   display: block;
}
.containerch .checkmark:after {
    left: 7px;
    top: 3px;
    width: 40%;
    height: 65%;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.answerhos {

}
.modind {
 overflow: inherit;
}
.iu {
 cursor:pointer
}
.iui {
  
    width: 18vh;
    height: 18vh;
    border-radius: 100px;
    top: 5vh;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;


}

.modind .hosind .promind .kompind {
 width: 100%;


}
.ciarka {
 margin-top: 10%;
}

.iuii {

  width: 115px;
    height:115px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    top: 5vh;
   display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.objednavkaformularo{
 
 float: right;
 padding: 5%;
 border-right: 2px solid black;
 
 vertical-align: middle;

}

.iui img{
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:inline-block;

}

.iuii img {
 
  
}




.idd {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.textik {
 font-size: 16px;
 width: 60%;
 height: 1vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.resized {
 display: none;
}

.penisnadpis {
 margin-left: 1%;
 
 color: rgb(236,212,146);
}

/* pokus o responsivitu */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    body {
     
    }

    #PART1 {
     display: none;
    }

    footer {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
    }

    .uo{
     margin-top: 0%;
    }
  

.penisnadpis {
 margin-left: 0%;
 
} 
.iui {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10vw;
}

.iuii {
  float: left;
 margin-left: 10vw;

}
    .uo {
     display: none;
    }
.resized {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 20%;
 width: 100%;


}
.texticek {
 font-size: 17px;
}
.ibutton {
 margin-top:5vh;

}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {

body {
 
}

#PART1 {
 width: 100%;

}


 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1550px) {
body {
 background-color: 
}
.textik {
 width: 85%;

}

#PART1{
 width: 90%;
}


}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
 body {
  background-color: 
 }

 #PART1{
 width:100%;
}
.textik {
 width:95%;
 font-size: 13px;

}

.uo {
 margin-top: 40%;
}



}

@media only screen and (max-height: 600px) {
 body {
 
 }
.telicko {
 height:100%;
}
footer {
 margin-top:  3%;
}
}
```